# Micorosft Access SQL - Counting Number of foreign key records across 3 related tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-query

I am experienced at VBA but new to SQL.

I am developing a test sheet program in MS Access for the plant that I work at. This test sheet program will be used across 3 product lines.

When an order is created, it can contain up to all 3 products. The products are unique enough that I cannot put them all into their own table. So I have broken the test sheets up into 3 tables, each table representing its respective product test sheet. Please see the image below for my relationship setup.

[image: Relationship Table]

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to design a query that will be my master list (outputting to a continuous form). The master list will show all orders, and also show how many units have been tested in each order. See below for my desired output.

My Issue: [image: The query is outputting the incorrect counts]

It is not properly counting the number of related records. See the linked photo.

I know my key field is Order Number but I am searching by Job name. Originally my key field was job name but then switched it to order number.

thank you for your time, I am happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: Should show sample data and desired output as text in question, not image. Do 3 aggregate queries then join those queries to TblJobName. JobName should not need to be duplicated into Sheet tables.

Comment: @June7 Thank you for your input I will not use pictures next time. I have incorporated your comments. Please review my answer and let me know if I could improve it in any way. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Consider joining three aggregate saved queries:

```sql
SELECT OrderNumber
     , COUNT(*) AS CountofCassetteTests 
FROM TblCassetteTestSheet
GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

```sql
SELECT OrderNumber
     , COUNT(*) AS CountofSentinelTests 
FROM TblSentinelTestSheet
GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

```sql
SELECT OrderNumber
     , COUNT(*) AS CountofHUVTests
FROM TblHUVTestSheet
GROUP BY OrderNumber
```

Then join to `TblJobName` in your final query (parentheses are required):

```sql
SELECT j.OrderNumber, j.JobName
     , c.CountofCassetteTests AS [# Of Cassettes Tested]
     , s.CountofSentinelTests AS [# Of Sentinels Tested]
     , h.CountofHUVTests AS [# Of HUV Tested]
     , j.JobEndDate, j.SPONumber
FROM ((TblJobName j
LEFT JOIN QryCassetteTestSheet c
    ON j.OrderNumber = c.OrderNumber)
LEFT JOIN QrySentinelTestSheet s
    ON j.OrderNumber = s.OrderNumber)
LEFT JOIN QryHUVTestSheet h
    ON j.OrderNumber = h.OrderNumber
```

Conceivably you can run all in one query using subqueries (and maybe one day even Common Table Expressions, CTEs, if the MS Access team ever enhances its older [SQL dialect](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar)):

```sql
SELECT j.OrderNumber, j.JobName
     , c.CountofCassetteTests AS [# Of Cassettes Tested]
     , s.CountofSentinelTests AS [# Of Sentinels Tested]
     , h.CountofHUVTests AS [# Of HUV Tested]
     , j.JobEndDate, j.SPONumber
FROM ((TblJobName j
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT OrderNumber, COUNT(*) AS CountofCassetteTests 
     FROM TblCassetteTestSheet
     GROUP BY OrderNumber) c
  ON j.OrderNumber = c.OrderNumber)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT OrderNumber, COUNT(*) AS CountofSentinelTests 
     FROM TblSentinelTestSheet
     GROUP BY OrderNumber) s
  ON j.OrderNumber = s.OrderNumber)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT OrderNumber, COUNT(*) AS CountofHUVTests
     FROM TblHUVTestSheet
     GROUP BY OrderNumber) h
  ON j.OrderNumber = h.OrderNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created 3 queries. Each query counts the number of tests for that product that are associated with an order number. Below you will see my code for

`QryCountofTestedHUV`

```
SELECT TblJobName.OrderNumber, TblJobName.JobName
(
SELECT
Count(*)

FROM
TblHUVTestSheet

Where TblHUVTestSheet.OrderNumber=TblJobName.OrderNumber
) AS CountofHUVTests
FROM TblJobName LEFT JOIN TblHUVTestSheet ON TblJobName.OrderNumber = TblHUVTestSheet.OrderNumber
GROUP BY TblJobName.OrderNumber, TblJobName.JobName;
```

From there I have gone into the relationships view, and linked `QryCountofTestedHUV.OrderNumber` to `TblJobName.OrderNumber`. Now I can add `CountofHUVTests` from query `QryCountofTestedHUV` as a field to my query, `QryAllJobs`! `QryAllJobs` is my master list I showed earlier.

I have repeated this 3 times for all 3 product lines and it works!